# Logging during calling state in Android

Tags: android

Everyboday. I am trying to log some information such as phonenumber, calling time and so on during calling state in android. I was tried to build with some codes following as below:

```
package com.test.dialuplog;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class IncomingBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    String mPhoneNumber;
    public static IncomingBroadcastReceiver pThis;
     @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            telephonyManager.listen(new CustomPhoneStateListener(context), PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

        }


     public class CustomPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {

            //private static final String TAG = "PhoneStateChanged";
            Context context; //Context to make Toast if required 
            public CustomPhoneStateListener(Context context) {
                super();
                this.context = context;
            }

            @Override
            public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
                super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);

                switch (state) {
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                    //when Idle i.e no call
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Phone state Idle", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                    //when Off hook i.e in call
                    //Make intent and start your service here
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Phone state Off hook", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                    //when Ringing
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Phone state Ringing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

}
```

And also I wrote some codes in AndroidManifest.xml like this:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />


 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">

         <receiver android:name=".IncomingBroadcastReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>     
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
</application>
```

After coded, I called to my phone with different one.
But nothing happened, This codes are followed from open source, but nothing happened. Are there anybody who has already experienced? If it is, Please teach me what I wrong. Thank you.